# How to get WIF SAML2 Extensions' Saml2AuthenticationModule to work in Windows Azure compute emulator?

Tags: iis-7, azure, httpmodule, wif, saml-2.0

In IIS Express, using the Saml2AuthenticationModule (from the [WIF Extension for SAML2 Protocol](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2011/05/16/announcing-the-wif-extension-for-saml-2-0-protocol-community-technology-preview.aspx)) results in the following application flow:

1. User goes to Service Provider URL that invokes `Saml2AuthenticationModule.Current.SignIn`(args);
2. The module routes a request to the Identity Provider.
3. Depending on the SP's AssertionConsumerService metadata, the IdP sends an SSO response back to the SP. In my current tests, this URL is "{rootdomain}/`ServiceProvider/saml/post/ac`". As far as I can tell, this URL is not configurable.
4. The module intercepts this response, does its thing to configure IClaimsIdentity, and then redirects flow back into the SP application (arg passed in step 1).

When targeting the Windows Azure Emulator instead of IIS Express, I changed the web.config to point to a different SP metadata file, with a different AssertionConsumerService that fits with the emulator URL:

```
<md:AssertionConsumerService index="1" 
    Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" 
    Location="https://127.0.0.1/ServiceProvider/saml/post/ac" />
```

When debugging in the azure compute emulator, the flow stops after step #3. When it reaches step #4, I end up looking at a 404 page for this URL:

```
https://127.0.0.1/ServiceProvider/saml/post/ac
```

**What's going on here? Isn't the module supposed to intercept this URL and process the SAML response? Why is this working in IIS Express but not in the azure compute emulator?**

Here is the web.config for the SAML stuff:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="Saml2AuthenticationModule" 
            type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Saml2AuthenticationModule"/>
        <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" 
            type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule"/>
    </modules>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

...

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
    <service>
        <audienceUris>
            <add value="https://www.mydomain.com/saml2/development/azure"/>
        </audienceUris>
        <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None"/>
        <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry">
            <!-- The set of trusted issuers. -->
            <trustedIssuers>
                <add name="urn:samples:identityprovider" thumbprint="59 fc 9a da 58 86 31 8d 1d d5 f8 a6 0f 9a 53 f8 09 fc 0e 63"/>
            </trustedIssuers>
        </issuerNameRegistry>
        <serviceTokenResolver type="Samples.Saml.Utilities.SampleServiceProviderSecurityTokenResolver"/>
        <!-- Enable saveBootstrapTokens so the token visualizer can show the raw SAML assertion. -->
        <securityTokenHandlers>
            <securityTokenHandlerConfiguration saveBootstrapTokens="true">
            </securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
        </securityTokenHandlers>
        <federatedAuthentication>
            <cookieHandler requireSsl="true"/>
        </federatedAuthentication>
    </service>
</microsoft.identityModel>
```

...

```
<microsoft.identityModel.saml metadata="saml2-azure.xml">
    <identityProviders>
        <metadata file="identityprovider.xml"/>
    </identityProviders>
</microsoft.identityModel.saml>
```

The entityID in saml2-azure is `https://www.mydomain.com/saml2/development/azure`, has the above AssertionConsumerService URL, and is in both the SP and IdP under test.